# React - Are class components ever used?

Tags: reactjs

I'm going through some courses that were made before react hooks were a thing, now I'm wondering if there is any reason at all to use class-based components over functional components now that hooks exist?

I can't seem to come up with a reason or scenario where a class-based component would be preferable, but maybe I'm just not aware of certain corner-cases where a class-based component would be the go-to choice.

Appreciate any feedback regarding this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I never write new components as classes, and frequently convert class ones to functions, **but** I usually still teach new developers how the class components work since the lifecycle methods are so much more declarative and are easier to understand and visualize. Then its easier to explain what hooks do, since you can compare to the named lifecycle methods. But once they're past the tutorial stage and working with real source code, its all functions.

Comment: As to corner-cases, as far as I know there is no functional equivalent to `componentDidCatch` so [error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) still have to be class components

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, really makes it clearer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class components are still used, but there is no particular reason to continue to do so.
Tthe Facebook team recommends that all new React code is hook-based functional components, and not class-based. You can mix class components and hook-based components, so there is no reason to rewrite your class components.

You can read more at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html

Answer (score 1):

At the company I work for we have mixture of both since we started using react before hooks. In my experience class components tend to have a lot more state logic, are fatter, tightly coupled, and harder to test. However, even though we're moving towards developing functional components, some people coming from a c# background tend to pick up class based components more easily. I would highly suggest using functional components but depending on the background of your team it might not hurt in the short run to use class based ones.

Answer (score 1):

The only good reason that I can think of for using class components these days would be to create error boundaries as:

> Only class components can be error boundaries.

From https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html